# get count of all positive values from a the last 150 rows at each row - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset where I have the column **Date** and **Values** for each row. It has both **+ve** and **-ve** values. I have to get a count of all positive values for the last 150 rows. IN each row. SO the 1st 150 rows will have null values. Then, the following rows will have have the count of last 150 **+ve** rows and similarly the **-ve** column will be filled with the count of negative values until that row.

I tried using :

```
def get_count_of_all_150_positive_rows_before_this_row(row):
    df1 = row.tail(2)
    df1 = df1.to_frame()
    print(df1.tail())
    # if df1['positive_values'] > 0:
        return (df1['positive_values'].count())


df.apply(get_count_of_all_150_positive_rows_before_this_row, axis=1)
```

Dataset:

```
Date        values      positive_values    negative_values
01/01/08    0.12344     
02/01/08    -0.12344        
03/01/08    -0.1234433      
04/01/08    -0.12344        
05/01/08    -0.1234433      
06/01/08    -0.12344        
07/01/08    -0.1234433      
08/01/08    -0.12344        
09/01/08    -0.1234433      
10/01/08    0.12344     
11/01/08    -0.12344        
12/01/08    -0.1234433      
13/01/08    -0.12344        
14/01/08    -0.1234433      
15/01/08    -0.12344        
16/01/08    -0.1234433      
17/01/08    -0.12344        
18/01/08    -0.1234433      
19/01/08    0.12344
```

Comment: Can you add output for +-5, instead 150? Also  15-20rows should be enough. thanks.

Comment: I've truncated your data.. a *minimal* example doesn't need all your rows. We can demonstrate logic with 5 instead of 150.

Comment: @Jason, please provide desired output, assuming last 5 rows, given the truncated data in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use pd.rolling() to perform a rolling count of the positives and negatives given the previous 'period' count.

```
period = 5
df['less_than_zero'] = (df['values']
                        .rolling(window=period, min_periods=period)
                        .agg(lambda x: (x < 0).sum()))

df['greater_than_zero'] = (df['values']
                          .rolling(window=period,min_periods=period)
                          .agg(lambda x: (x > 0).sum()))
```

This should give you what you want

```
Out[30]: 
         date    values  less_than_zero  greater_than_zero
0   01/01/08  0.123440             NaN                NaN
1   02/01/08 -0.123440             NaN                NaN
2   03/01/08 -0.123443             NaN                NaN
3   04/01/08 -0.123440             NaN                NaN
4   05/01/08 -0.123443             4.0                1.0
5   06/01/08 -0.123440             5.0                0.0
6   07/01/08 -0.123443             5.0                0.0
7   08/01/08 -0.123440             5.0                0.0
8   09/01/08 -0.123443             5.0                0.0
9   10/01/08  0.123440             4.0                1.0
10  11/01/08 -0.123440             4.0                1.0
11  12/01/08 -0.123443             4.0                1.0
12  13/01/08 -0.123440             4.0                1.0
13  14/01/08 -0.123443             4.0                1.0
14  15/01/08 -0.123440             5.0                0.0
15  16/01/08 -0.123443             5.0                0.0
16  17/01/08 -0.123440             5.0                0.0
17  18/01/08 -0.123443             5.0                0.0
18  19/01/08  0.123440             4.0                1.0
```

**Note**: It's worth throwing a few 0s into the sample data set to ensure that you are not miss-attributing them in this case. (*We're not, but still*)

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

tail = df.tail(5)
pos = len(tail[df['values']>0])
neg = len(tail[df['values']<0])

df['pos_values'], df['neg_values'] = np.nan, np.nan
df.loc[df.index.values[-5:], 'pos_values'] = pos
df.loc[df.index.values[-5:], 'neg_values'] = neg

#         Date    values  pos_values  neg_values
# 0   01/01/08  0.123440         NaN         NaN
# 1   02/01/08 -0.123440         NaN         NaN
# 2   03/01/08 -0.123443         NaN         NaN
# 3   04/01/08 -0.123440         NaN         NaN
# 4   05/01/08 -0.123443         NaN         NaN
# 5   06/01/08 -0.123440         NaN         NaN
# 6   07/01/08 -0.123443         NaN         NaN
# 7   08/01/08 -0.123440         NaN         NaN
# 8   09/01/08 -0.123443         NaN         NaN
# 9   10/01/08  0.123440         NaN         NaN
# 10  11/01/08 -0.123440         NaN         NaN
# 11  12/01/08 -0.123443         NaN         NaN
# 12  13/01/08 -0.123440         NaN         NaN
# 13  14/01/08 -0.123443         NaN         NaN
# 14  15/01/08 -0.123440         1.0         4.0
# 15  16/01/08 -0.123443         1.0         4.0
# 16  17/01/08 -0.123440         1.0         4.0
# 17  18/01/08 -0.123443         1.0         4.0
# 18  19/01/08  0.123440         1.0         4.0
```